# How to sync a git repo to a mirrored repo

Tags: git, synchronization, mirror

I want to mirror a git repo to my local repo, and wish to 
timely sync them, I did like this:

```
git clone --mirror source_url source_repo
cd source_repo
git push --mirror local_url
```

Now I have mirrored the source repo to my local repo, I could clone my
local repo like this:

```
git clone local_url local_repo
```

But since the source repo is going update, how could I keep them sync?

Answer (score 3):

Any local repository, either mirrored or working, can be synced with `git remote update`

```
cd REPO
git remote update
```

Answer (score 2):

Exactly for this purpose I created [git-sync-mirror](https://hub.docker.com/r/enteee/git-sync-mirror).

> ## git-sync-mirror
>
> *A simple synchronization container image for git repositories over HTTPS*
>
> Features:
>
> - Authentication with https tokens
> - If needed, use a different HTTPS Proxy for source and destination
> - TLS-Trust On First Use: Seamlessly run this container behind a https scanning proxy
> - Skip certificate checks (don't do that)
> - Configure time to sleep between synchronization attempts
>
> ### Usage
>
> ```sh
> $ docker run \
>    --rm \
>    --env SRC_REPO=source \
>    --env DST_REPO=destination \
>    --env SLEEP_TIME=30s \
>    enteee/git-sync-mirror
> ```
>
> *Note*: The container is designed for synchronization over https with
>   supported authentication using access tokens. For example replace
>   source with
>   https://github-user:github-access-token@github.com/Enteee/git-sync-mirror.git

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches here. You can select one that is convenient to you.

1. The approaches discussed in https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/195456/keeping-git-repositories-on-different-hosts-in-sync (writing scripts, etc)
2. Add a custom hook to your git repo - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-git-hooks-to-automate-development-and-deployment-tasks
3. If you are using a 3rd party tool like BitBucket, they should have built in solutions or plugins for this. Ex : https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.englishtown.stash-hook-mirror/server/overview

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I wanted to sync two remote repositories(A and B), after pushing from local repository.

```
Local repository pushes to remote repository "A"
Remote repository "A" pushes to remote repository "B"
```

To avoid adding always two repositories for each local repository, I have created post-update hook on remote repository "A" with one line of code:

```
git push --all --force
```

Now deployment remote repository "B" is always automatically up-to-date with central remote repository "A".

Answer (score 0):

I have for years used the following scheme:

- On one remote server (server1) create one or more master git repositories for my distributed clients. All non-local users (on serverX) clone the desired repos locally and push updates to the master.
- On another remote server (server2) I clone the master repos as mirrors. Then I set a cron job to periodically run "cd REPO; git remote update". That remote server is currently being set up on Digital Ocean and I have scheduled weekly backups on it. In the past I have mirrored the master repos on at least two different remote servers for safety.